# When animating, how fire the callback only when all elements are done?

Tags: jquery, animation, callback

When animating in jQuery, what's best practice for firing a callback only when ALL elements are done animating and not for each element?

For example:

```
$('.someElements').fadeOut('fast', function() {
  // dont do this until ALL elements are done fading
}
```

Comment: Am I confused on your question? All of those elements should finish their animation at the same time. They all get the duration of 'fast', so they all finish at the same time.

Comment: Do you want to fire the callback only **once**?

Comment: Tejs: As Justin mentions below, a callback will fire for each element in the collection.

And Felix, yes, I only want to fire the callback once. Decided to go with microspino's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be a snippet to try:

```
var numberOfElements = $('.someElements').length;

$('.someElements').fadeOut(fast, function() {
  if( numberOfElements-- > 0 ) return;
  alert('call the Fireman!'); 
});
```

The alert Is just a placeholder to the end-callback you need to fire.

EDIT (another way):

You can also catch all the elements but not the **last** one.

```
$('.someElements').not(.someElements:last).fadeOut();
```

and then add a fadeOut with callback only to It

```
$('.someElements:last').fadeOut(fast, function (){ 
   // do something, it's the end of the world
};
```

Comment: Great! But, to make the comparison become true, the condition should be (--numberOfElements > 0) right? To decrease the variable before the comparison.

Comment: -- is a LeftHandSideExp operator. The expression decrease first then evaluate the comparison. Say you are on the last loop: you have 1 element, the expression goes this way: 1-- > 0 ? False, don't return, go to next line and fire the alert call.

Comment: For this to work,  the condition should be (--numberOfElements > 0)

Comment: These answers are out of date.  Since jQuery 1.6 the best way to achieve this is to use `.promise()` and `.done()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great question, as per the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/):

> If multiple elements are animated, it is important to note that the callback is executed once per matched element, not once for the animation as a whole.

To work around this limitation you could:

- Enumerate all of the elements matching `.someElements`, and set up a separate callback for each one.
- Have a `count` variable that keeps track of how many total callbacks there are.
- In your callback, decrement `count` until it reaches 0.

When count reaches 0, all callbacks are complete, and you will be guaranteed that all elements are done animating. From here, you can then have special code in your callback that does whatever you need to do...

Comment: Thanks Justin! This seems a bit elaborate if you just want the callback to fire once, but is great for when you need something to happen for each animation as well. For this simpler case I'd go with microspino's answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

More recent releases of jQuery (version 1.6 and later) include the idea of a [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/). Using this function eliminates the need for a workaround. For example:

```
// define the animation on many elements
$('.someElements').fadeOut('fast');

// define the promise that is called once all element animations are done
$('.someElements').promise().done( function() {
    // put callback actions here
});
```