# Return a result from nested animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have an animation loop used to manipulate individual letters. It's wrapped in a timer in order to create a delayed offset. Each letter animates 100 ms later than the previous. I need to figure out how I can tell when the full animation is complete but I'm having some trouble because of the different types of nesting in use.

I've tried a few different things including trying to return a value from the animation, then the timer, and then the $.each function, but I'm sure this is off. I also was thinking I might be able to use the promise provided by jQuery's animate function, but not sure exactly how to implement this. Any advice here would be appreciated :] thank you

Here is my current code:

```
var offset = 200;
//drop individual letters down out of view
    function dropLetters($letters){

        var len = $letters.length - 1;

        $letters.each(function(i){

            var $letter = $(this);

            setTimeout(function(){

                $letter.animate({ top: offset + 'px' }, 300, function(){
                    if( i >= len ){
                        return $(this).promise();
                    }
                });

            }, 100 * i );

        });

    }
```

Edit: Sorry I realize I have omitted the offset variable. I added this back - it was just set to a value of 200.

Also, I realize this question is similar to another, but it also seems to differ from it. The answers provided here give a couple of different approaches that aren't present in the other question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery - defer callback until multiple animations are complete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220878/jquery-defer-callback-until-multiple-animations-are-complete)

Comment: @nem That example does not show a good solution because the OP is calling `setTimeout` around the call to `animate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approach utilizing `.promise()` <strike>`$.when()`</strike> , `Function.prototype.apply()`, `$.map()`, `.delay()`. Note substituted chaining `.apply()` to `.promise()` for `$.when()` to return `this` as jQuery object containing elements instead of array containing jQuery objects at `.then()`

```js
var offset = 100, duration = 300, delay = 100, curr = 0;

function dropLetters(elems) {
  return $.fn.promise.apply(elems, $.map(elems, function(el) {
    return $(el).delay(curr += delay).animate({top: offset + "px"}, duration)
  }))
}

dropLetters($("button")).then(function() {
  console.log("complete", this)
})
```

```css
button {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button>
  0
</button>

<button>
  1
</button>

<button>
  2
</button>
```

---

Alternatively, using `$.when()` , `.queue()`

```js
var offset = 100, duration = 300, delay = 100, curr = 0;

function dropLetters(elems) {
  return $.when(elems.queue(function (next) { 
    $(this).delay(curr += delay).animate({top:offset + "px"}, duration, next())}))
}

dropLetters($("button")).then(function() {
  console.log("complete", this)
})
```

```css
button {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button>
  0
</button>

<button>
  1
</button>

<button>
  2
</button>
```

Comment: There it is! A much better looking jQuery solution :) I still prefer to use jQuery only when necessary ;)

Comment: @JuanMendes Have one even briefer

Comment: The suspense is killing me!

Comment: This is not quite what the OP wants, each letter waits for each animation to finish before the next button drops. See my example

Comment: Yes, you mentioned that earlier. The animations at OP does this as well; or appears to from this vantage . `i + duration` will always be `duration` more than previous iteration . Also , linked Question approach should return expected results when substituting `.delay()` for `setTimeout`

Comment: @JuanMendes https://jsfiddle.net/ukqceuL7/1/ . Also possible using `.done()`, `.ready()`; though they each could have issues with chaining `.then()` outside of array of functions passed as parameter being called before promises in array completes

Comment: Very nice, looks even better

Comment: Thank you, this is a totally different approach that I wasn't familiar with and it works out well

Answer (score 2):

You can make a promise out of each `setTimeout` call and you don't need to track by yourself that all the async operations have finished.

```
function dropLetters($letters){
  var promises = [];
  $letters.each(function(i){
    var $letter = $(this);
    promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function(){
        $letter.animate({ top: offset + 'px' }, 300, function(){
            resolve();
        });
      }, 100 * i );
    });               
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Note that you may need a [Promise polyfill](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill) See  http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises

One of the benefits of my answer over the existing ones that check index is that you would have to modify the code in two places if you changed the animation to be backwards. See my version below where the letters fly out backwards (and forward).

```js
function dropLetters($letters, backwards) {
  var promises = [];
  $letters.each(function(i) {
    var $letter = $(this);
    promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $letter.animate({
          top: '-100px'
        }, 300, function() {
          resolve();
        });
      }, 100 * (backwards ? $letters.length - i : i));
    }));
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
}

dropLetters($('p')).then(function() {
  alert('finished')
});
  
dropLetters($('span'), true).then(function() {
  alert('finished')
});
```

```css
p, span {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>

<hr style="clear: both"/>

<span>B</span>
<span>B</span>
<span>B</span>
<span>B</span>
<span>B</span>
<span>B</span>
<span>B</span>
<span>B</span>
<span>B</span>
<span>B</span>
<span>B</span>
<span>B</span>
<span>B</span>
<span>B</span>
<span>B</span>
<span>B</span>
```

Comment: Just noticed , where is `offset` defined at `js` at OP ?

Comment: Probably a global? Not relevant to the question, is it?

Comment: Yup, sorry, I realize I missed including offset. Thanks for the tip about not needing to track the async, was not aware I was doing extra work

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$.Deferred()` , `.resolveWith()`

```
function dropLetters($letters) {

  var len = $letters.length - 1;

  var dfd = $.Deferred();

  $letters.each(function(i) {

    var $letter = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() {

      $letter.animate({
        top: offset + 'px'
      }, 300, function() {
        if (i >= len) {
          dfd.resolveWith($(this));
        }
      });

    }, 100 * i);

  });

  return dfd.promise()

}
```

Comment: @JuanMendes Yes, several ways to achieve expected results. Would generally utilize `.queue()` for such a process. Why use  `Promise` constructor at each iteration ? No value appears set at `resolve()` ? Should `$letters` be resolved as `Promise` value ? Though was not certain if only last element should be resolved or collection `$letters` ; used last element at post

Comment: A new promise will still work even if they finish out of order (if the OP changes the code so that the first one takes longer than the last).

Comment: @JuanMendes Above post could probably be re-written using `$.when()` , `.apply()` , `$.map()` or  jQuery `.promise()` ; attempted to adjust original post as little as possible at present possible solution

Comment: My first answer also modified it as little possible. Then I realized that what the OP was doing was duplicating the work that `Promise` does for you. I wanted to stay away from jQuery specific syntax, I know the OP is using it, but I abhor using jQuery when standard solutions exist. I would enjoy seeing a nicer looking jQuery solution though

Comment: JuanMendes _"I would enjoy seeing a nicer looking jQuery solution though"_ What is lacking using single `$.Deferred()` ?

Comment: You are  still checking the index to make sure all have finished

Comment: @JuanMendes _"You are still checking the index to make sure all have finished"_ See alternative approach at new Answer

Answer (score 1):

As thers have stated you may use $.Deferred()` 
Just to illustrate i added an example based on given code. ;-)

```js
//drop individual letters down out of view
    function dropLetters($letters){
        var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
        
        $letters.each(function(i,elem){
            var $letter = $(elem);

            var timer = setTimeout(function(){        

                $letter.animate({ top: $letter.offset().top-100 }, 300, function(f){
                   if(i+1>=$letters.length){// last letter was animated
                       deferred.resolve();
                   }
                });
              
            }, 300*i );

        });
        return deferred;

    }
dropLetters($('p')).then(function(){alert('finished')});
```

```css
p{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p><p>A</p>
```

Comment: This is not an optimal solution, if you're using Promises, you should not track by yourself when the asynchronous  operations finished

Comment: How is your solution different from `js` at http://stackoverflow.com/a/35807369/ ?

Comment: @guest271314 it uses `resolve` and yours uses `resolveWith`? IMHO it's clearer (at least for me) but overall, pretty much the same thing. It also fails if you remove the letters backwards instead of forwards. Just saying... my answer works in both cases....

Comment: Good point reversing order would break functionallity. So i'm with @Juans answer.

Comment: @JuanMendes Not following you here _" It also fails if you remove the letters backwards instead of forwards"_

Comment: @guest271314 It will say it's finished after the first letter unless you change two places in the code. See my example